# Failing to create certificate for my API server using CertBot

Tags: https, certbot, amazon-lightsail

I have an API server running on AWS Lightsail. I am trying to make my API server support HTTPS requests.

On the Lightsail side, I have setup IIS so that it runs my API server code. My API server works online as expected when using HTTP.

I want to support HTTPS. From my understanding that requires three things:

1. IIS binding on HTTPS/port 443
2. Lightsail Networking's Firewall allowing HTTPS procotol
3. The IIS using a trusted certificate

From my understanding I can generate a certificate using CertBot, but in order to use it I must have a domain connected to my server's IP.

I have purchased a domain on GoDaddy and added a new A record that points `@` to my Lightsail server's IP. Now, when I use the domain and the API (/) online I can see it works.

However, when running `certbot certonly --standalone` on my server's CMD and specifying my domain, I am hit with an error and my certificate generation fails:

```
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: standalone). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: <MyDomain>
  Type:   connection
  Detail: <MyServerIP>: Fetching http://<MyDomain>/.well-known/acme-challenge/AjAQQ-6IMMTzYuR1BaofWnmbIfS4dyjDMye3CXA69q8: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the challenge files from the temporary standalone webserver started by Certbot on port 80. Ensure that the listed domains point to this machine and that it can accept inbound connections from the internet.
```

As far as I understand, I have tested successfully that the listed domain is this machine and that it can accept requests from the internet.
If so, what is my issue?

Thanks in advance. I'm sorry if I'm missing anything obvious - I am extremely inept at web development and server management.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve my goal (setup HTTPS for my server) by using a system other than CertBot in the end. Just like CertBot, it was just a mediator for Let's Encrypt.

I followed [this guide](https://www.snel.com/support/how-to-install-lets-encrypt-with-iis-on-windows-server-2019/) on using win-acme to generate a certificate. This tool also automatically connected it to IIS, so HTTPS worked instantly when it was done.

I will also add that another thing I did was configure a static IP address in Lightsail.

Comment: This answer is not self contained. Please avoid depending on external links.